# Newly created Pydev Django Project does not include initial package with Settings.py etc

Tags: django, eclipse, settings, pydev

When creating Django Pydev projects in Eclipse the default config package is created automatically with the following structure:

```
MyApp
    __init__.py
    settings.py
    urls.py
    wsgi.py
manage.py
```

Today I created a Django Pydev project and those files and initial package were not created.

I have tried several times to create new Django Pydev projects but the the initial structure is not being created.

This problem only just started happening. I have not had the problem prior to today.

Running this on the command line does work:

```
django-admin.py startproject mysite
```

The files and project structure are created correctly. So it's just Eclipse and Pydev that fails.

I am using Django 1.4, Pydev 2.5 and Eclipse Indigo 3.7 on Ubuntu 11.1

Comment: So what are you look for here? If you're concerned that PyDev doesn't create the project correctly, file a bug with the PyDev project. Otherwise, create the project the standard way with `django-admin.py`, and then just create a project in eclipse with that existing project.

Comment: I thought that perhaps there might be a setting or configuration that I could check which might have changed. I created the project the standard way which works so I'll stick to that. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: After creating a project with django-admin.py I went back into Eclipse and tried again and lo the project was created successfully!

Answer (score 17):

I had the same issue today but it turned out that it was because my project name was not handled - eg "My Project".  The space threw it.  Calling the project "MyProject" worked a treat.

From the cmd line it gives the following error - which eclipse is not returning:

> c:\django-admin.py startproject "My Project"
>
> Error: "My Project" is not a valid project name.  Please use only numbers, letters and underscores.

Comment: I probably just encountered the same issue: Calling the project "test" kinda doesn't work too well either...

Comment: Similar issue for me... but apparently it was because of my dashes!! "test-application" does not work, while "testApplication" does work.

Answer (score 4):

I ran into the same issue on win7.

I also tried to run django-admin.py manually from command line. Instead of generating a project, it opened up a default editor for .py file. Then this was clear to me that it was because I installed some program which registered itself as the default program to run .py file. In my case it was WebMatrix2 but even if you don't install anything, there is a good chance that it is set to notepad by default by win7.

I knew that PyDev will actually run django-admin.py to generate the project. So my guess was that PyDev tried to run the .py file. Then since the program to run it was not python.exe, nothing was generated. PyDev ignored this error so there was nothing in the project.

Then the fix is simple. Choose any .py file, right click to open the properties window and change the default program to python.exe.

Now go back to Eclipse and try to create a django project again. You should be able to see manage.py file and other files created.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I was having this problem - I tried to create a project called test-django, and it wouldn't add manage.py etc to the structure. So I tried doing the same thing with django-admin.py and it failed and said only numbers, letters and underscores!

So the problem is that eclipse/pydev fail to report this error and make the project anyway!

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue today (Win7).  I had been using eclipse, PyDev and Django for a while and had no problems.  Tried to create a new project today, and it failed to populate the project folder with manage.py etc.

I happen to have both Python 32 and 64 bit installed, but Django 32 bit.  I forgot to select the 32 bit interpreter when I created the project, and so it called the 64 bit interpreter to run django-admin.py and failed silently.  Once I selected the 32 bit interpreter it created the project folders as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Met the same issue when creating a PyDev Django project in the virtual environment.

Unable to find out any effective solution either in Chinese or English. After a few tries, I've managed to resolve it

When creating the PyDev Django Project, instead of putting your project folder in the virtual environment folder, you need to choose another directory outside.

[Eclipse Pydev Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jzsyH.jpg)

I tend to believe this is a PyDev bug, as I can put my django project folder anywhere using the command:

django-admin startproject PROJECT_NAME.

It works fine in the virtual environment folder. Refer to my setup environment below:

Eclipse Oxygen: 4.7.1a
PyDev         : 6.1.0.201711051306
Django        : 1.11.7

Answer (score 0):

i met this issue, too.

However, after devastatingly searching online. I'd decided to re-install the plugin with a brand new Eclipse for Java EE Developer, Version: Indigo (previous was Classical Eclipse, Indigo).

And it worked!

Answer (score 0):

Just to note, provided you have the latest PyDev, this should work (previous versions had issues with Django 1.4) -- it's possible that it's just missing a refresh (i.e.: it's creating it but not showing in the PyDev package explorer).

Just refresh it and see if it works -- and make sure you have 'refresh using native hooks' and 'refresh on access' selected on window > preferences > workspace.

If you still have an issue, please check if they really weren't created in the filesystem and if they weren't check your error log for some error there and report back.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue.

Fixed by doing Help -> Check for Updates.

Updated Eclipse and restarted.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question was asked long time ago, but I faced the same problem with Eclipse Neon and I figured out possibly there is a bug.

I guess you used File>New>PyDev Project to create a project. I used MyProject as the name of the project so I did not have any space in the name, and therefore project name could not be the issue. You should see 3 steps to configure your project, while the 3rd one is not shown. The 3rd step is Django Setting and if you cannot get to that step, your files will not be created.

Instead if you use CTRL+N, you will see a different wizard and this way it takes you to 3rd step and all the file will be generated.